# How to set the inflated view full screen or fill_parent?

Tags: android

This XML is inflated from my main activity, I would like to know if how do I set the inflated view as full screen or fill_parent as shown in the XML, because when I test my app it will give me a half size screen shown on the right side.

[image]

The first pic is from my pc, and the second is from my tab.

Here's my XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/splash"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_16sdp"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_16sdp"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/_16sdp"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/_16sdp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/g1btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/g1tv2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="BUTTON"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_70sdp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/g1tv2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="&quot;THIS&quot;"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_70sdp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/g1tv2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="66dp"
        android:text="TAP"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_70sdp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="GAME 1"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_50sdp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's my MainActivity.Java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);   
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

        View game1 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.game1, null);
        RelativeLayout item = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.Main);
        item.addView(game1);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the xml ?

Comment: I have edited the post.

Comment: dude i edited your code, it was incomplete. now that its formatted can you please let us know are you using Activity or AppCompatActivity? or another

Comment: I'm just using Activity. Thank you for editing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not your Wrapping layout, you are adding a view to another View with no layout params with respect to the parent.

Tell your inflated view, this is your parents layout params, for example:

```
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.game1, null);
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id. Main);
view.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
relativeLayout.addView(view);
```

this should solve your problem without just putting a LinearLayout wrapping it.

Good Luck and Happy coding!

Comment: THANK YOU SOOOOO MUCH! :) You made my day! hahahaha, I am really thankful to this Stackoverflow site, it is very useful! Thanks inner_class7!

Answer (score 0):

Add this code before `setContentView();`

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: I already have done that. However, when I inflate a view, it's not doing the output that I was expecting as shown in the Graphical Layout

Answer (score 0):

**Use Linear layout as the parent View and give android:orientation = "vertical". Relative Layout is a a Layout where the positions of the children are described in relation to each other or to the parent.If you want to use relative layout then you have to use the addrule property or else all the child will be drawn over the previous child.**

```
   View game1 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.temp, null);
    LinearLayout item = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main);
    item.addView(game1);
```

Comment: I was using the library called SDP. That's why I'm using _#SDP.

Comment: I have removed the Library that I'm using and tested your code, and still.. it's giving me a half size view :( Please help.

Comment: try this code i also try it on sdp its work fine . i have edited  my code

Comment: Still the same huhuhuh, my relativelayout's background is a full screen image. However it's not working ...

Comment: I was try replace your Relative Layout to LinearLayout its work. you can inflate on it.try it

Comment: Hi Vishal thank you for your help :) However, I found a very nice and simple solution and it is the answer of inner_class7. Once again thank you :)

Comment: @codesofdave yeah. because you used relative as parent Layout.